# Delete record into table and get the number of deleted rows

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I want to create a SQL query which deletes records older than 1 hour:

```
@Override
    public List<Cvvs> deleteOldRecordsByDate(LocalDateTime created_at) throws Exception {

        String hql = "delete from " + Records.class.getName() + " e where e.created_at <= :created_at";
        TypedQuery<Records> query = entityManager.createQuery(hql, Records.class).setParameter("created_at", created_at);
        List<Records> records = query.getResultList();
        return records;
    }
```

But how I can get the number of the deleted records?

Answer (score 4):

You use the `executeUpdate` on bulk updates/deletes and its return value is the number of affected rows:

```
int records = query.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: I think it will not give deleted id for more than one row.

Comment: @Mak but OP did not ask about ids of deleted records, but the amount of deleted records.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using Spring Data JPA I think it's better to use repository query method which will return the number of deleted records, for example:

```java
public interface RecordRepo extends JpaRepository<Record, Integer> {

    @Modifying
    @Query("delete from Record r where r.createdAt <= ?1") 
    int deleteByCreatedAt(LocalDateTime createdAt);
}
```